# Spring Data JDBC: Repository does not save nested entities starting from third level

Tags: java, mariadb, spring-data-jdbc

I'm tying to persist a tree-like entity with structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `task` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `parent_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;

@Data
@Table
public class Task {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
    
    @MappedCollection(idColumn = "parent_id")
    private Set<Task> subItems;
}

public interface TaskRepository extends org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository<Task, Integer> {}
```

Initialize entity:

```
Task task = new Task();
Task task2= new Task();
Task task3= new Task();

task.setSubItems(Set.of(task2));
task2.setSubItems(Set.of(task3));

taskRepository.save(task);//auto-generated method
```

Spring data jdbc performs insert operation for 'task2' and 'task' only. 'task3' ignored.

Java11, Spring-data-jdbc 2.0.3, Mariadb 10.3

Comment: Could you please show us the repository class?

Comment: Repository code is simple as possible:

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
public interface TaskRepository extends CrudRepository<Task, Integer>  {}

Answer (score 0):

In the current form this is misusing Spring Data JDBC, since the aggregates (and aggregate roots) aren't properly separated.

`Task` seems to be an aggregate root and therefore the references from one `Task` to its children should be via id and not via object reference.
See https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/24/spring-data-jdbc-references-and-aggregates for more details about this.

I therefore recommend to make each `Task` its own aggregate.

Of course, Spring Data JDBC should probably throw an exception instead of silently ignoring part of the model. Please raise an issue for that on https://jira.spring.io/projects/DATAJDBC/issues